# OpenGL texture is not showing

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

I'm trying to display a simple texture (from an array) in OpenGL, but I just get a blank white screen.

My code to generate the texture:

```
GLbyte textureData[] = { 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 255 };
GLsizei width = 2;
GLsizei height = 2;


glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glGenTextures(1, &textureName);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureName);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB8, width, height, 0, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_RGB8, (GLvoid*)textureData);
```

And the display code:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureName);
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);
glVertex2f(-1.0, -1.0);

glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0);
glVertex2f(1.0, -1.0);

glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0);
glVertex2f(-1.0, 1.0);

glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0);
glVertex2f(1.0, 1.0);
glEnd();

glutSwapBuffers();
```

I know the problem is with the textures as I can draw solid shapes on the screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default minification filtering setting is to use mipmaps. Since you do not provide all mipmap levels down to 1×1 and didn't switch to a filter method that does not require mipmapping, texture sampling will be skipped.

You have to add setting the filter method to something non-mipmapped, like this:

```
glTexImage2D(…);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

Or provide a full stack of image levels.

Also there's a problem with the `glTexImage2D` call: `GL_RGB8` is not a valid token for the data format. Explicitly sized format tokens are permitted only for the *internal* format. However, for starters you should probably use the unsized tokens (just `GL_RGB` without the `8`) anyway (explicit size should be used only, when it really matters, e.g., for certain precision requirements or to avoid conversion costs for streaming texture updates).

Comment: I added the line you suggested (and another for magnification), but still only a white screen displays unfortunately.

Comment: @acernine: Ah, I saw another problem. `GL_RGB8` is not a valid enum for the data format.

Comment: @datenwold Sorry, I'm new to this as I'm sure you can tell! I was under the impression that both the source and destination textures were of RGB8 - why is this not the case?

Comment: @acernine: Size and layout of the data are determined in entirety by the `format` and `type` parameters. The `internal_format` parameter used to be just the number of channels (1, 2, 3 or 4) in the first version of OpenGL (20 years ago) but over time more control over the internal format was required, hence the additional tokens. But for the data buffer the two parameters that accompany it offer far better control. So it's essentially down to legacy and a missed opportunity in API design. Hindsight is 20/20.

Comment: So if I understand correctly the right thing to do is change RGB8 to RGB - when I do this nothing changes.

Comment: @acernine: You (accidently?) swapped `type` and `internal_format`. For your convenience: https://pastebin.com/Ch7TanK9